# How to sort table by date using javasript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a responsive table that displays the data it's given. In one of the 4th columns, there're the dates. I simply want a button to sort the table by the date in that column.

An example of the dates I have: 4/29/2021, 8:26:07 PM

I tried using parse, I tried jquery, I tried simply using Arrays. Yet I have failed to properly arrange the table by date.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Use `new Date("4/29/2021, 8:26:07 PM").getTime()` and sort using these values.

Comment: As said above, you should *convert* the date string to **timestamp** and then you can easily to numerical sorting

Comment: I think I am an idiot. That worked like a charm. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 var array = ["4/28/2021, 8:26:07 PM","4/29/2021, 8:26:07 PM"];
 array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime());
```

You will get the output:

```
["4/29/2021, 8:26:07 PM","4/29/2021, 8:26:07 PM"]
```